# Haskell Type Synonyms for Functions

Tags: function, haskell, types

Say we have the following in Haskell,

```
type Bag a = a -> Int

data Gems = Sapphire|Emerald|Diamond|Ruby deriving (Show)

myBag :: Bag Gems
myBag Sapphire = 3
myBag Diamond = 2
myBag Emerald = 0 

emptyBag :: Bag Gems
emptyBag Sapphire = 0
emptyBag Diamond = 0
emptyBag Emerald = 0
```

How would we define a function addItem such that addItem x b adds a single occurrence of item x to bag b?

Comment: Can you define `addSapphire`, for example?

Comment: (Tempted to flag this question as too localised, not sure)

Comment: So i tried, something like this:  > addItem :: Bag a -> a -> Int >addItem x y =  x y + 1  that is pattern matching over type of Bag so say i called my additem function with myBag and Emerald i would get 1 but that is not really adding the item to the original myBag?

Comment: @user1950055, right, everything is immutable in Haskell, so if you want to modify the Bag, you have to return a new one instead.  So your function should take a `Gems` and a `Bag Gems` and return a new `Bag Gems`.

Comment: I'm curious why you are using this representation of `Bag`, rather than, say, an assoc list: `[(Sapphire, 3), (Diamond, 2)]`.

Answer (score 2):

You want a function of the type

```
addItem :: Gems -> Bag Gems -> Bag Gems
```

noting the definition of `BagGems` this is the same as

```
addItem :: Gems -> (Gems -> Int) -> Gems -> Int
```

thus, we expect the definition of `addItem` to begin

```
addItem gemToAdd bag gem = --some Int expression
```

okay, so lets think about the logic also

1. If `gem` is a different Gem from `gemToaAdd` we should get out what ever `bag` gives us
2. If it is the same than we should get one more

thus

```
addItem gemToAdd bag gem = if gem == gemToAdd then (bag gem) + 1 else bag gem
```

which you could also write

```
addItem gemToAdd bag gem | gem == gemToAdd = (bag gem) + 1
                         | otherwise       = bag gem
```

now, this will produce an error since `Eq` is not defined for `Gems`.  The simplest way to fix that is to define

```
data Gems = Sapphire|Emerald|Diamond|Ruby deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and you are done

Comment: So i tried something like this, i defined a function count as: <br/>    > count :: Bag a -> a -> Int
> count x y = x y
Then as suggested by you...a function addItem <br/>
    > addItem :: Eq a => a -> Bag a -> Bag a
    > addItem gemToAdd bag gem
    >  | gem == gemToAdd = (bag gem) + 1
    > | otherwise       = bag gem     <br/> However i get a ERROR - Type error in application
*** Expression     : Emerald myBag
*** Term           : Emerald
*** Type           : Gems
*** Does not match : a -> b <br/> surely Emerald should be able to be used as Gems?

Comment: @user1950055 `Emerald myBag` is in the wrong order.  Function application goes `function argument` so `myBag Emerald`.  The type error you got is that `Emerald` is not a function, but you are using it where a function is expected.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't change anything in Haskell, everything is immutable. So what you're trying to do right now is wrong.

```
myBag Sapphire = 3
```

Will always be 3.

So you will have to return a new bag instead of changing it.

Also, I think it would be better to create a list of Gems instead of pattern matching. As such:

```
data Gems = Sapphire|Emerald|Diamond|Ruby deriving (Show, Eq)

type Gem = (Gems, Int)
type Bag = [Gem]
```

You can now do things such as

```
[(Ruby, 30), (Sapphire, 20)] :: Bag
```

for example.

Next we want to be able to adjust this bag.

```
removeGem :: Gems -> Bag -> Bag
removeGem _ [] = []
removeGem gem (x:xs) | gem == (fst x)  = removeGem gem xs
                     | otherwise = x : removeGem gem xs
```

This code will let you remove a gem from a bag. It's very simple, it just goes through the list and checks each item if it's the selected gem. If that's not the case it will add it to the function list. In the end it will return a new list without the selected gem.

With this function we can add gems to a bag with the following code:

```
addToBag :: Gem -> Bag -> Bag
addToBag item@(gem,amount) bag = 
  case lookup gem bag of 
    Nothing -> item : bag
    _       -> let (Just oldAmount) = lookup gem bag
               in (gem, (amount + oldAmount)) : (removeGem gem bag)
```

This code will let you add new gems to a bag like so:

```
(Diamond, 10) `addToBag` [(Ruby, 30), (Sapphire, 20)] :: Bag
```

Will return:

```
[(Diamond,10),(Ruby,20),(Sapphire,30)]
```

"lookup" is a function that looks up a "key" in a list of tuples. The key being the first tuple value, in our case the Gems.

If the lookup doesn't find the gem we want to add, it will simply append it to the list.

If however it does find it, we will store the amount it has of that gem into "oldAmount", delete the gem and add the new amount and old amount together to create a new gem for your bag. For example:

```
(Ruby,20) `addToBag` [(Diamond,10),(Ruby,20),(Sapphire,30)]
```

Will return:

```
[(Ruby,40),(Diamond,10),(Sapphire,30)]
```

instead of:

```
[(Ruby,20),(Diamond,10),(Ruby,20),(Sapphire,30)]
```

So it adds up the amount instead of adding the same gem name over and over.

If you want to find a gem and amount from your bag, you can simply use the "lookup" function.

I hope this answers your question.